# TFS Project List is not updated after adding a new project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I created a new project (it was the 5th project in my account) in my TFS account at ***.visualstudio.com. I launched Visual Studio 2010, clicked `Team->Connect to TFS`, logged in with my login and password.
I created a new project (Console Application). But when I right click and choose `"Add Solution to Source Control"`, it shows me a window with 4 projects instead of 5 (i.e. it doesn't show a new TFS project).
I tried to restart the Visual Studio 2010 and to reboot my computer. Neither helped.
What may cause such a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual studio frequently has issues with caching info from TFS. I’d suggest you refresh this several times and eventually restart VS. If that doesn’t work you should check if that user has enough permission to see the project.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you intended to create a new Team Project in TFS but instead created a new VS Project. Instructions for creating a Team Project in TFS are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms181477%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Team Projects are organizational units in TFS, while a "Project" in VS typically represents a single assembly.

Comment: I created a TFS project first (it was my 5-th project for my account at *visualstudio.com), then I created a new project in Visual Studio 2010. Finally, I wanted to add a VS project to the TFS project, but it didn't show me the name of the 5th (newly created project) in the "add" window.